# Triggering JavaScript events in Qunit tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am trying to test that when a user clicks in my form the existing error message will go away. For some reason the last test is failing and i'm not sure why. I'm fairly new to jQuery and Qunit.

#### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture">

    <form>
        <input name="text" />
        <div class="has-error">Error text</div> 
    </form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="qunit.js"></script>
<script src="../list.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 test("errors should be hidden on key press", function() {
     $('input[name="text"]').trigger('keypress');
     equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
});

 test("errors not be hidden unless there is a keypress", function() {
      equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), true);
 });

test("errors should be hidden on click", function() {
     $('input[name="text"]').click();
     equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
 });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### list.js

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $('input[name="text"]').on('keypress', function() {
         $('.has-error').hide();
     });

     $('input[name="text"]').on('click', function() {
         $('.has-error').hide();

     });
 })
```

Comment: seems like your test is happening before list.js.   what if you wrap your tests in `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {}`

Comment: @SaidKholov The first two test pass but the last one that involves the click does not.

Comment: try triggering touch event as well

Comment: @SaidKholov When I run all the tests together the last one fails. But when I run the last test by itself it passes.

Comment: that's interesting. Does it make a difference if you swap third and second tests?

Comment: @SaidKholov The first one fails.. When I refresh the page it alternates failing for those two tests. Maybe I need to wrap each test in a function.

Comment: I was wrong. I will try again

Comment: @SaidKholov OK. Wrapping the tests in functions doesn't work. Seems like an odd bug

Comment: Looks good now, here is upvote for you))

Comment: @SaidKholov Thanks. I don't have enough rep yet to upvote.

Comment: That's ok. No worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setupModule() {
    $('input[name="text"]').on('click', function() {
         $('.has-error').hide();
    })
    $('input[name="text"]').on('keypress', function() {
        $('.has-error').hide();
    });
}

module('tests', {setup:setupModule});

test("errors should be hidden on key press", function() {
     $('input[name="text"]').trigger('keypress')
     equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
});

 test("errors not be hidden unless there is a keypress", function() {
     equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'), true);
 });


test("errors should be hidden on click", function() {
     $('input[name="text"]').click()
     equal($('.has-error').is(':visible'),false);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3v08v1e/13/

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Could you explain the module function?

Comment: Tests remove event handlers I suppose and module hooks reassign it back

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems based on the documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got this working.

```js
/* ./inventory.js */
var hide_error = function () {
  $('input').on("keypress", function() {
    $( ".has-error" ).hide();
  });
}

/* ./tess.js */
QUnit.module( "module A ", {
  before: hide_error
});

QUnit.test("errors not be hidden unless keypresses", function ( assert ) {
  assert.equal( $('.has-error').is(':visible'), true, "Not Hidden" );
});

QUnit.test("errors should be hidden on keypresses", function ( assert ) {
  $('input').trigger("keypress");
  assert.equal( $(".has-error").is(':visible'), false, "Hidden" );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.js"></script>

<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture">
  <form>
   <input name="text">
   <div class="has-error">Error Text</div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="./inventory.js"></script>
<script src="./tests.js"></script>
```